# Send API From Nodejs (express js) Project to Flutter Project

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, dart

When I try in thunder client, the parameters are sent without any problem, but when I switch to the flutter project, the parameters do not go to the node js API.

Flutter code

```
var https = await http.post(
              Uri.parse(
                  'https://api.birqr.click/check-user'),
              body: {
                'userId': '64708d926cf77c7ebb047199',
              },
            );
```

status

```
400
{status: 'error', message: 'userId field required'}
```

I added cors plugin to my node js project but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you send from flutter with http package's body comes as request.body, not as request.query. You should apply this in your node js project.